# Why xState is not working with react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, xstate

I am trying to change the status of the button when the user clicks, it's all part of the xstate, where the buttons are getting, according to the State the button is going to work.in typescript, it's working fine but not in react hooks

```
const ProjectStatus = {
  UN_ASSIGNED: 'UN_ASSIGNED',
  ASSIGNED: 'ASSIGNED',
  CHECKED_OUT: 'CHECKED_OUT',
  CHECKED_IN: 'CHECKED_IN',
  QC_START: 'QC_START',
  QC_FAIL: 'QC_FAIL',
  QC_PASS: 'QC_PASS',
  CUSTOMER_REVIEW: 'CUSTOMER_REVIEW',
  CUSTOMER_REJECT: 'CUSTOMER_REJECT',
  RE_ASSIGN: 'RE_ASSIGN',
  HOLD: 'HOLD',
  DONE: 'DONE',
  CUSTOMER_APPROVE: 'CUSTOMER_APPROVE'
};
function MachineButton() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const params = useParams();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(false);
  const [current, send] = useState({ ...ProjectStatus });


  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const projectEntity = useSelector((states) => (states.taskDetails.entity));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTaskById(params.id));
  }, []);
  const toggleMachine = (currentState, action) => {
    const nextState = machine.transition(currentState, action);
    if (currentState !== nextState.value) {
      send(ProjectStatus[nextState.value]);
      dispatch(updateTask({ ...projectEntity }));
    }
  };

  const getButton = (currentState) => {
    if (currentState !== undefined) {
      const nextStates = machine.states[currentState].on;
      if (Object.keys(nextStates).length !== 0) {
        return (
          <div>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
              aria-controls="simple-menu"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              {Object.keys(nextStates)[0]}
            </Button>
            <Menu
              id="lock-menu"
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              keepMounted
              getContentAnchorEl={null}
              open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
              onClose={handleClose}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'center',
              }}
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'center',
              }}
            >
              {Object.keys(nextStates).map((action, index) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={action}
                  selected={index === currentState}
                  onClick={() => toggleMachine(currentState, action)}
                >
                  {action}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>

          </div>


        );
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.actions}>
      {getButton(projectEntity.status)}
    </div>


  );
}


export default MachineButton;
```

I am getting status is undefined but when I reload the button, the values are updating

this is the error I am getting.

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
 181 | 
  182 | 
  183 | return (
> 184 |   <div className={classes.actions}>
      | ^  185 |     {getButton(projectEntity.status)}
  186 |   </div>
  187 |
```

Is there something that I missed out, kindly do rectify, what else do I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might happen because when code gonna get to `getButton(projectEntity.status)`, `projectEntity` `useSelector` result still haven't calculated, and therefore it still undefined. Just add an `|| {}` to your decoration to avoid it

```
const projectEntity = useSelector((states) => (states.taskDetails.entity)) || {}
```

Or checker before activation

```
projectEntity && getButton(projectEntity.status)
```